# How to verify a java VariableElement can be passed to an ExecutableElement?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

If I have a `javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement` that represents a variable of type `List<SomeObject>`, and an `javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement` that represents a method with one argument of type `List<? extends SomeObject>`, how can I verify that my variable type can be passed into my method type?

I started to try and write a `javax.lang.model.type.TypeVisitor` to try and compare types ignoring wildcard types, but I'm not sure if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Obvious, but kinda useless solution: let the method call be generated (which I am assuming you to be doing), wait until last compilation round and check if an error occurred via return value of `RoundEnvironment#errorRaised()`. You may not be able to generate any sources afterwards.

If you really want to perform that verification for ugh… science, see below.

---

As you should already understand, it is technically not possible to assign an element to to another element. You have to go from elements to types (e.g. `TypeMirror`s). Be very careful while doing that!

1. Always check source code for errors before proceeding. `ErrorType` is crazy: the compiler will let it to participate in strange assignments and generally treat it as some magical "anything will do" wildcard (not to confuse with actual `WildcardType`). I am personally using slightly modified version of Google Auto [SuperficialValidaton](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/google/auto/common/SuperficialValidation.java) for this, and so should you, unless somebody else have already validated all elements for you.
2. Never assume, that an element have type of some specific kind (e.g. `DeclaredType`). Your code will be very hard to refactor and adapt to new language features if you do.
3. *Do* use [TypeMiror#getKind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html#getKind--) to check for specific type kinds and cast to specific subtypes of `TypeMirror` when that makes sense. Visitor paradigm is there to make forward compatibility easy, but you shouldn't use it when you *need* a specific type kind like `DeclaredType` to proceed.

Since you are programming within `java.lang.model` framework, I will assume, that you know about utility classes [Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html) and [Elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html) and how to get instances of them. Let's call those instances `types` and `elements`.

#### Convert both your VariableElement and ExecutableElement to TypeMirrors:

You haven't posted specific code and haven't told anything about where do your method and variable come from and what are they like, so here is the most generic approach imaginable:

```
VariableElement variable = ...
ExecutableElement method = ...

TypeMirror variableType = types.asMemberOf(c1, variable);
ExecutableType methodType = (ExecutableType) types.asMemberOf(c2, method);
```

The `c1` and `c2` in the code above refer to the most specific types of classes, that will contain your variable and method at runtime. For example you may have classes c1 and c2 like these:

```
class c1Base<X extends Number> {
  protected X variable;
}

interface c2Base<Y extends Number> {
  void method(Y parameter);
}

class c1 extends c1Base<BigInteger> {}

abstract class c2 implements c2Base<Byte> {}
```

You get types of c1 and c2:

```
// If you happen to know, that c1 and c2 have their own type arguments,
// and which type arguments may be used at run time, specify those here

DeclaredType c1 = types.getDeclaredType(elements.getTypeElement("co.exampl.c1"));

DeclaredType c2 = types.getDeclaredType(elements.getTypeElement("co.exampl.c2"));
```

And types of variable and method parameter will evaluate to `BigInteger` and `Byte`, as if there were no generic parameters to begin with!

Naturally, you may also happen to be in a situation, when refining away type parameters does not make sense: you have received both method and variable by calling `getEnclosedElements` and have no clue, what container type can possibly be used at runtime. In that case just use [asType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#asType--):

```
TypeMirror variableType = variable.asType();
ExecutableType methodType = (ExecutableType) method.asType();
```

#### Check if type of variable can be assigned to type of parameter

Whether Javac allows variable of type X to be passed to method with parameter type Y is based on two factors:

1. Can X be assigned to Y in general case?
2. A good deal of type inference magic.

If X can be assigned to Y without extra factors involved, the method call is surely going to succeed too:

```
TypeMirror methodParameterType = methodType.getParameterTypes().get(0);
if (types.isAssignable(variableType, methodParameterType)) {
  // return early, the call will be allowed
}
```

But what if it isn't, but the call may succeed anyway because of type inference? Unfortunately, as of Java 8 there seems to be no public API for accessing compiler's type inference and no `java.lang.model` classes use it under the hood. You can have a type `List<? extends Date>` and a method like this:

```
<X extends Serializable> void foobar(List<X> parameter) throws RemoteException;
```

and no matter, how you go about retrieving TypeMirrors, `isAssignable` won't return `true`, despite the fact, that the method can be called with parameter of such type.

The [part](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) of Java specification, concerning type inference, is huge and uses many facilities, not available to annotation processors via public API (computing least upper bound etc.) It also has tendency to change a lot in major language revisions. Implementing the corresponding logic yourself would be highly unwise.

If I were you, I would give up on trying to perform definitive verification in advance and instead let Javac itself make a decision. Just generate the method call and let it fail if user has supplied incorrect types somewhere. You can improve your early prediction by checking if variable type and method parameter type are both `DECLARED` and neither has any type arguments, but still allow the call to be generated if that is not the case:

```
if (methodParameterType.getKind() == TypeKind.DECLARED
  && variableType.getKind() == TypeKind.DECLARED
  && types.isSameType(methodParameterType, types.erasure(methodParameterType))
  && types.isSameType(variableType, types.erasure(variableType))) {
  // type inference is extremely unlikely to interfere
  return types.isAssignable(variableType, methodParameterType);
}

// allowed the call ourselves, if compiler forbids it, it will emit
// a compilation error with descriptive message, so user should probably
// be able to figure things out
```